# I need to add a <br> after a word when viewing in 480 width screen

Tags: css, class, tags, break

I need to add a `<br>` after a word when viewing in 480 width screen.

Ex. desktop

```
<img src="images/phone_icon.png">1-000-000-0000(Int.)
<img src="images/phone_icon.png">1-000-000-0000(US)
```

i need to add a `<br>` after `(Int.)` when screen gets to 480width so it 
should go to the next line.

Is there a pseudo class or css code to add that tag?

thank you in advance

Comment: thanks for editing,, i didn't know how to make it display like that.

Comment: There is a button for code blocks or you can simply indent them 4 spaces.  For inline code you surround it in tick marks.

Comment: thanks for the tip James. Just started using stackoverflow to learn css3/html5 stuff and im liking it. there's a lot of professional web developers really are helpful and share their knowledge. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do a trick. Add empty `span` after "(Int.)" like this

```
<img src="images/phone_icon.png">1-626-389-8668(Int.)
<span class="break"></span>
<img src="images/phone_icon.png">1-866-933-7368(US)
```

and manage the things by `css` and `media queries`

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px){
  .break {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Typo: `display` not `disaply`...

Comment: This is bad practice, not trying to flame, but you should never use empty elements unless you absolutely have to and for that matter using an inline element as a block element is no good either.

Answer (score 2):

It probably makes the most sense to add a wrapper to each group of image and text and handle that with a media query.  Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2uUx4/

**Update HTML:**

```
<span class="wrapper">
    <img src="images/phone_icon.png"/>1-626-389-8668(Int.)
</span>
<span class="wrapper">
    <img src="images/phone_icon.png"/>1-866-933-7368(US)
</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .wrapper{
        display: block;    
    }
}
```

Comment: A variation of this answer: 

You can also put a wrap around the number itself and use a pseudo element: http://jsfiddle.net/RUHQ6/1/

Comment: @KennyGHanson Also workable.  I was just trying to think of why this line break was needed and it seemed the idea was to keep the image and text together on a line.  So semantically it seemed more appropriate to group the image and text as they seemed to be treated as a unit.  Though it's entirely possible I read too far into it.